# Change request method in axios interceptor

Tags: javascript, axios

I'm trying to change an axios `GET` request into a `POST` request using an interceptor. The method seems to be changed, but my params are still affixed to the URL, instead of being sent in the `POST` body.

```
    axios.get(payload.url, {
      params: payload.params || {}
    })

    axios.interceptors.request.use(
      function (config) {
        // check request method -> use post if many params
        if (MY_CONDITION) {
          if (config.method === 'get') {
            console.log('changed to post')
            config.method = 'post'
          }
        }
        return config
      }
    )
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you tried passing the `params` as `data` instead?

Comment: @CD.. that was it. I didn't realize that `params` and `data` are different, I thought `params` in a `POST` will just be added into `POST body`. Great, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to CD..'s comment, I found the solution. `Params` are always attached to the request-URL, while I'd need to use `data`, since that's what ends up in the `POST body`. Posting in case other's need it:

```
  config.method = 'post'
  config.data = config.params
  config.params = {}
```